# Apply background color to width based on content width

Tags: css

I just want to apply background-color based on the width of the content occupied.
I have used following two snippets.

```
// this applies for the entire row and not for the text occupied
<p style="padding: 10px; background: #77bb77; color: #fff; border-radius: 10px; text-align:right">
   Text me
</p>

// if text is larger than width of <p> then text wraps to next row
// and it is not applying padding correctly on the second row 
<p style="text-align: right">
  <span style="padding: 10px; background: #77bb77; color: #fff;border-radius: 10px;">
     Text me
  </span>
</p>
```

Please check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/adww60ry/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the style `display: inline-block;`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: ensure  you mentioned that this style "display:inline-block" is for  **span element** since OP is adding a background color to this container .. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <span style="padding: 10px; background: #77bb77; color: #fff;border-radius: 10px;display:inline;">
 Text me
```

seems to work fine. https://jsfiddle.net/ndt2db12/